# Azure API Management /Azure function authentication approach?

Tags: azure, api, authentication

Confused on which type of authentication method to use for Azure API Management/Azure Functions:

1. User name & password(saving keys in keyvault)
2. Token(non expiring/expiring)
3. Subscription key
4. IP Filter
5. Oauth2

If we go with option 5:

1. Does grant_type,client_id,client_secret and scope are the required keys in order to generate the token?  And can we encrypt the values before giving it to vendor?
2. How can we change the token authorization url from login.microsoftonline.com/tenanted to our dns? Do we need to use azure front door or is there any other option?

Answer (score 1):

There's no unique/right answer based on what you've described. I usually recommend choosing one Identity Provider (IDP) (e.g. Azure AD) + Product Subscription at API Management.

Identity Provider will take care to generate auth token, and your Azure Function or API Management can validate against IDP to guarantee the token is valid and issued by the IDP.

If you'll charge based on API calls, you use the API Management Subscription Key to filter/count and charge properly the consumers of your API. Also, only callers with a valid Subscription Key will be able to consume your API.

Now answering your other two questions:

1-) If you're using Azure AD as IDP, then yes

2-) you can't, unless you'll use your own IdP (e.g. Identity Server)